# Rails - Backround process, where to place "view" related logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, rake

Let's say I have an application that needs to post (daily) several stuff on **Facebook**, through **Graph API**. Assuming that I know how to create the rake file that will be called periodically, my question is:

Right now the rake file is directly calling a **model method** that deals with getting the data and perform the required actions to post to Facebook.  I have something like this:

```
 def post_last_entries_to_facebook
 # Get user information
 # Build message
 end
```

I believe it makes sense to deal with stuff like getting user information and so on in the model, but I need to create that message that will be pushed into the Facebook (via **Koala gem**).

At the end of the day I want to call this from the model:

```
facebook_graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(token)
facebook_graph.put_wall_post(message)
```

But, **how and where** do I create that message if I can't render views/templates since **ActiveController** is not present in the models.  What's the correct way of doing so in these cases?